# After updating the iframe source the vimeo ended event not working

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

After updating the iframe Vimeo video URL through AJAX call the ended event is not fire at the end of the video. Why this happening?
This is the code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var vimeoplayer;
    var iframe = document.querySelector('videoPlayer');
    vimeoplayer = new Vimeo.Player(iframe);
    vimeoplayer.on('ended', function () {
       alert('Ended');
    });

});
```

On AJAX Success i am doing like this below

```
vimeoplayer.element.src = newURL;
```

Comment: And what's your question about this?

Comment: After updating the URL. the event not fire

Comment: Please share more details. What do you mean by "the event not fire"? Where do you bind the event to the reloaded iFrame?

Comment: vimeoplayer.on('ended', function () {
       alert('Ended');
    });